# DHCP asigna IP de diferente VLAN

Tags: redes, ip

En nuestra empresa teníamos un ASA 5510 que sustituimos por un FortiGate 200E utilizando dos switches Catalyst 2960 en pila.

A partir de que hicimos ese reemplazo (ASA a Forti) el switch asigna direcciones IP en el rango 192.168.1.0/24 cuando debería asignar IPs en el rango 192.168.3.0/24. Los Catalyst son los que hacen el trabajo de DHCP, no el fortigate. Por cierto, en el rango 192.168.1.0/24 no está definido ningún pool DHCP.

Esto pasa la primera vez que un dispositivo se conecta pero si se desconecta y reconecta alrededor de 4 veces, se le asigna una IP correcta en el rango 192.168.3.0/24 pero esto es bastante molesto ya que los usuarios se han quejado mucho de este inconveniente.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: ¿Desactivaste el servicio de DHCP en el Fortigate antes de conectarlo a la red?

Comment: Sí, el Fortigate no tiene configurado DHCP ni como server ni como relay.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la utilería [DHCP TEST](http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/10/dhcp-test-client/) de Vladimir Panteleev, es un tipo sniffer de peticiones DHCP, te mostrará que equipos están solicitando IP en tu LAN y que servidor se los está asignando.

Este es un ejemplo de los resultados donde 192.168.AA.XX es la dirección del servidor y 192.168.AA.YY es la IP asignada al cliente con MAC Addreess X0:W2:Q7:7Q:QQ:16 (reemplazadas por IP ficticias para ejemplo).

```
  Listening for DHCP replies on port 68.
Type "d" to broadcast a DHCP discover packet, or "help" for details.
Received packet from 192.168.AA.XX:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=X0:W2:Q7:7Q:QQ:16 hops=0 xid=FAEDA540 secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.AA.YY siaddr=192.168.AA.XX giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  9 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     58 (Renewal (T1) Time Value): 120 (2 minutes)
     59 (Rebinding (T2) Time Value): 210 (3 minutes and 30 secs)
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 240 (4 minutes)
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.AA.XX
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.AA.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.AA.XX
     15 (Domain Name): AA.com
```

Puedes consultar mas información del [protocolo DHCP aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) y de su [arquitectura aquí](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd183602(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Aquí el output de DHCP TEST, ¿me podrían ayudar a interpretarlo? Efectivamente primero hace una consulta al server DHCP 192.168.3.252 y le da una dirección pero después consulta al 192.168.1.252 el cual no es un servidor DHCP y ni siquiera pertenece a la VLAN a la que está conectado el equipo.

Comment: Intenta asignar en tu computadora una dirección del segmento 192.168.1.x y hacerle ping a 192.168.1.252 a ver si te contesta, en dado caso intenta accesar a esa IP por web para ver si te da una pantalla de configuración

Comment: Puedes postear el output completo por favor para poderlo interpretar

Answer (score 0):

Listening for DHCP replies on port 68.
Type "d" to broadcast a DHCP discover packet, or "help" for details.
d
Sending packet:
  op=BOOTREQUEST chaddr=9F:CC:B5:97:13:CE hops=0 xid=B4AB41D3 secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=0.0.0.0 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  1 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): discover
Received packet from 192.168.3.252:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=9F:CC:B5:97:13:CE hops=0 xid=B4AB41D3 secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.3.216 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=

9 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.3.252
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 2592000 (4 weeks and 2 days)
     58 (Renewal (T1) Time Value): 1296000 (2 weeks and 1 day)
     59 (Rebinding (T2) Time Value): 2268000 (3 weeks, 5 days, and 6 hours)
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     15 (Domain Name): GRUPOKABAT
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.3.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.100, 200.57.64.85, 200.57.64.86,
189.204.33.66, 189.204.33.67
Received packet from 192.168.3.252:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=D8:E5:6D:AA:07:90 hops=0 xid=298FAFB2 secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=0.0.0.0 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  2 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): nak
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.252
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=D8:E5:6D:AA:07:90 hops=0 xid=298FAFB2 secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.92 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): ack
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 259200 (3 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=D8:E5:6D:AA:07:90 hops=0 xid=EDF16019 secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.92 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 259200 (3 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=D8:E5:6D:AA:07:90 hops=0 xid=EDF16019 secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.92 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): ack
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 259200 (3 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4

Answer (score 0):

Aqui el output completo.

Listening for DHCP replies on port 68.
Type "d" to broadcast a DHCP discover packet, or "help" for details.
s
Unrecognized command.
d
Sending packet:
  op=BOOTREQUEST chaddr=81:57:AF:DC:E8:B5 hops=0 xid=390B0C8C secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=0.0.0.0 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  1 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): discover
Received packet from 192.168.3.252:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=81:57:AF:DC:E8:B5 hops=0 xid=390B0C8C secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.3.222 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=

9 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.3.252
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 2592000 (4 weeks and 2 days)
     58 (Renewal (T1) Time Value): 1296000 (2 weeks and 1 day)
     59 (Rebinding (T2) Time Value): 2268000 (3 weeks, 5 days, and 6 hours)
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     15 (Domain Name): GRUPOKABAT
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.3.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.100, 200.57.64.85, 200.57.64.86,
189.204.33.66, 189.204.33.67
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=00:56:CD:42:2A:E5 hops=0 xid=A5D630A4 secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=0.0.0.0 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  2 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): nak
     61 (Client-identifier): 01 00 56 CD 42 2A E5
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=00:56:CD:42:2A:E5 hops=0 xid=A5D630A5 secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.11 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 7776000 (12 weeks and 6 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=C8:1E:E7:04:18:3F hops=0 xid=A3256468 secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=0.0.0.0 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  2 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): nak
     61 (Client-identifier): 01 C8 1E E7 04 18 3F
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=70:81:EB:5A:E4:2C hops=0 xid=CCC04A94 secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.30 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 7776000 (12 weeks and 6 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=70:81:EB:5A:E4:2C hops=0 xid=CCC04A95 secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=0.0.0.0 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  2 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): nak
     61 (Client-identifier): 01 70 81 EB 5A E4 2C
Received packet from 192.168.3.252:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=F8:16:54:0E:37:7E hops=0 xid=78105A76 secs=0 flags=8000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=0.0.0.0 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  2 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): nak
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.252
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=F8:16:54:0E:37:7E hops=0 xid=78105A76 secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.18 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): ack
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 259200 (3 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=F8:16:54:0E:37:7E hops=0 xid=476CDB0D secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.18 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 259200 (3 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=F8:16:54:0E:37:7E hops=0 xid=476CDB0D secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.18 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): offer
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 259200 (3 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4
Received packet from 192.168.1.254:67:
  op=BOOTREPLY chaddr=F8:16:54:0E:37:7E hops=0 xid=476CDB0D secs=0 flags=0000
  ciaddr=0.0.0.0 yiaddr=192.168.1.18 siaddr=0.0.0.0 giaddr=0.0.0.0 sname= file=
  7 options:
     53 (DHCP Message Type): ack
     54 (Server Identifier): 192.168.1.254
      1 (Subnet Mask): 255.255.255.0
     51 (IP Address Lease Time): 259200 (3 days)
      3 (Router Option): 192.168.1.254
      6 (Domain Name Server Option): 192.168.1.254
     26 (Interface MTU Option): 05 D4